# How do I "remove" a list from a list of lists, and also an element from a list?

Tags: ocaml

I need to fin a way to remove a list from a list of lists given a certain element to find. so for example a function called "remove x list" will remove the list that contains x. I am trying to use List.filter but i have no idea how it works. The full function would be: if x is in a list then delete the list, if -x is in a list, delete the element -x from the list. any help or guidance?

Comment: You should be more specific and make more of an effort, What (concretely) have you tried, and why (specifically) does it not work? Then we can help you. If you expect people to just give you the answer, and then use that, there's a high likelihood you'll get caught cheating. Stack Overflow is usually monitored by teachers and TAs to prevent exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is using a pattern matching

for instance you wanna remove an element from a list so basicly when this element is equals to the deconstruction element you match, you return the list without this element...

You can use a head function to store the list you iterate and use a "copy" of this function in the recursive function.

Have you tried using the absolute value for the -x thing ? You can do a quick check for the absolute value in your pattern matching

Good luck !

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
let lst = [[1;2;3;];[4;5;6;];[1;2;3;];[4;5;6];]
let ans = List.filter (fun l -> not(List.exists (fun x -> x = 5) l)) lst
```

ans is:

```
[[1; 2; 3]; [1; 2; 3]]
```

Comment: Hey so i tried replacing my funfilter function by your "ans" function but i added a list and an int as arguments and i get the error saying that the function requires a classic list and not a list of lists...I haven't changed any of the code and i get the error in the function simplifie at the part when i call (funfilter i clauses)
 let funfilter elem xs =
  List.filter (fun l -> not(List.exists (fun x -> x=elem) l)) xs
;;

Comment: ans isn't a function. ans is a list of lists.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Could you give use a sample list of lists and an element you would like removed from that list of lists and the final list of lists.

Comment: Update! I understood what my error was (ans being a list of lists instead of a function) and I fixed my function. everything works now! thanks for the help even though you were advised otherwise.

Comment: `List.exists` feels a little clunky here. Maybe `List.mem`? E.g. `let ans = List.(filter (fun l -> not @@ mem 5 l) lst)`